# how to delete all records in a particular table before excel import using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please How do I delete all existing records, refresh and reset the table before I Save new records. I want to do it from my controller.

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult Create(ITEM items)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _itemsService.AddCity(thirdparties);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "We cannot add this items. Verify your data entries !");
        }

        return View(items);
    }
```

I have an N-Tier layer

1. Infrastructure
2. Repository
3. Web(Presentation

**Infrastructure**

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null);
    T FindById(object id);
    T FindByEntity(T entity);
    T FindByString(object strValue);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
   }


    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> items = DataContextFactory.AdminEntities.Set<T>();
        return (predicate == null) ? items : items.Where(predicate);
    }

    public abstract T FindById(object id);

    public abstract T FindByString(object strValue);

    public abstract T FindByEntity(T entity);

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DataContextFactory.AdminEntities.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(entity);

        DataContextFactory.AdminEntities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T entity)
    {
        T item = FindByEntity(entity);

        if (item != null)
            DataContextFactory.AdminEntities.Set<T>().Remove(item);

        DataContextFactory.AdminEntities.SaveChanges();
    }


}
```

**Repository**

```
    public class CitiesManager: ICitiesManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<CITIES> _citiesRepository;

    public CitiesManager(IRepository<CITIES> citiesRepository)
    {
        _citiesRepository = citiesRepository;
    }

    public CITIES City(Int32 cityID)
    {
        return _citiesRepository.FindById(cityID);
    }

    public IEnumerable<CITIES> Cities()
    {
        return _citiesRepository.FindAll().ToList();
    }

    public void AddCity(CITIES cities)
    {
        _citiesRepository.Add(cities);
    }

    public void RemoveCity(Int32 cityID)
    {
        _citiesRepository.Remove(City(cityID));
    }
}
```

My model classes are in the infrastucture

Infrastructure --> Repository --> Web

Comment: How are you storing your existing records?

Comment: I use N-Tier: Infrastructure -> Repository -> Web.  I store on recored at a time. **        public ActionResult Create(ITEM items)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _itemsService.AddCity(thirdparties);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "We cannot add this items. Verify your data entries !");
        }

        return View(items);
    }**